# how do I create a if-else based function to extract string

Tags: r

string extraction using a defined function

I wrote a code to extract a portion of the string but the code doesn't run. It doesn't give me any error either. Please tell what am I missing. I am trying pass an input argument named address and return a value

```
    notes_address <- function(address) {
      address1 <- tolower(address)
      if(grepl("sent to.*. for del ", address1)) {
        address1 <- gsub(".*?sent to(.*?)(for del.*|$)", "\\1", )
      }  
      else {address1 <- NA}
      return(address1)
    }
```

For example, if `a <- "when you go sent to backstreet ave del to Mrs Kenwood"`, I expect the output to be: `"backstreet ave"`

Comment: You´re missing an argument in  `address1<-gsub(".*?sent to(.*?)(for del.*|$)", "\\1", )`. If you write `address1<-gsub(".*?sent to(.*?)(for del.*|$)", "\\1", address1)` should work.

Comment: @csmontt, please post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any `for` characters in your example string, so your function return NA because in the `else` part of your function you return NA. You can't have the expected output here. To have the expected output with your function:

```
notes_address <- function(address) {
  address1 <- tolower(address)
  if(grepl("sent to.*. del ", address1)) {
    address1 <- gsub(".*?sent to(.*?)(del.*|$)", "\\1", address1)
  }  
  else {address1 <- NA}
  return(address1)
}

a <- "when you go sent to backstreet ave del to Mrs Kenwood"
notes_address(a)

[1] " backstreet ave "
```

But I am not sure it is what you want. If it is, I would advise you to use the `stringr` library with the `str_extract` function:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(a,"(?<=sent to ).+(?= del)")
```

Gives the same output as your function